# Emacs, GDB, and multiple X windows

Tags: emacs, gdb

I use `gdb-many-windows` in `emacs` for my debugging.

Recently, I discovered how to move a buffer to [another X window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Creating-Frames.html) using `C-x 5 2`.

I find it convenient: since I use multiple displays, I can have one window with source and variables, and gdb's command line in another window.

But my problem is when I perform a step-by-step in `gdb`: when it opens another source file, it does that in the same window where the command line is located, while I expect it to be updated in the other window.

Does anybody know how to tweak `gdb` or `emacs` to do that? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `display-buffer-reuse-frames` does [address exactly this "issue"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#Choosing-Window-Options). Session-wide setting in configuration file:

```
(setq-default display-buffer-reuse-frames t)
```